# HashTableの派生クラスを作ると、追加した変数がHashTableのKeyとして扱われる。これの回避方法は?

Tags: powershell

(具体的なコードに変更しました)
PowerShellで`HashTable`の派生クラスを作ろうとしています。

```
class DerivedHT : HashTable{
    [ScriptBlock]$GetKeyBlock

    DerivedHT():base(){
        $this.GetKeyBlock = { $args[0] }
    }

    Add([object]$elem){
        if( $null -eq $this[$elem] ){
            $this[$elem] = @()
        }
        $this[$elem] += $elem
    }

    [int]OccurrencesOf([object]$elem){
        return(($this[$elem]).Count)
    }

    [object]Includes([object]$elem){
        return( $null -ne $this[$elem])
    }
}
```

このようなクラスを定義すると、プロパティ`GetKeyBlock`が自動的に`HashTable`の`Key`として扱われてしまうのですが、これを回避する方法はないでしょうか?

```
$dht = [DerivedHT]::new()

@(1,3,5,7,9).foreach{ $dht.Add($_) }
@(3,7).foreach{ $dht.Add($_) }

'----- keys -----' | Write-Host
$dht.Keys | Write-Host

'----- Values -----' | Write-Host
$dht.Values | Write-Host
```

実行結果
----- keys -----
**GetKeyBlock**
9
7
5
3
1
----- Values -----
**$args[0]**
9
7 7
5
3 3
1

Comment: PowerShell 5.1と7.3で確認しましたがそのような挙動はなく、`1` のみが返されました。再現可能な具体的なコードを提示してください。例えば `$dht.Add(1='one')` はエラーになります。

Comment: ご指摘により、実際に現象が発生するコードに変更しました。お知恵を拝借できると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

原因がわかりました。再現コードをもう少し整理すると

```
class DerivedHT : HashTable{
    [ScriptBlock]$GetKeyBlock
    Add([object]$elem){
        if( $null -eq $this[$elem] ){
            $this[$elem] = @()
        }
        $this[$elem] += $elem
    }
}

$dht = [DerivedHT]::new()
$dht.GetKeyBlock = { $args[0] }  # コメントアウトすれば再現しない
@(1,3,5,7,9).foreach{ $dht.Add($_) }
@(3,7).foreach{ $dht.Add($_) }
'----- keys -----' | Write-Host
$dht.Keys | Write-Host
'----- Values -----' | Write-Host
$dht.Values | Write-Host
```

で再現し、もちろん原因は `$dht.GetKeyBlock = { $args[0] }` 行を実行したことであり、ここをコメントアウトすれば発生しなくなります。

つまり、

> プロパティ`GetKeyBlock`が自動的に`HashTable`の`Key`として扱われてしまう

は誤解で、**プロパティの存在**は問題ではなく、正しくは**プロパティへ代入を行うこと**が原因です。

---

PowerShellでは.NET本来の機能だけでなく、PowerShell独自の機能を追加するため、各クラスはPowerShellが派生クラスを作っています。プロパティに代入を行うと`HashTable`に追加されるのもその一つとなります。
このことはドキュメントにも記されていて、

[about_Hash_Tables - プロパティ名の競合の処理](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.3#handling-property-name-collisions)

> キー名が `HashTable` 型のいずれかのプロパティ名と競合する場合は、 `psbase`組み込みメンバー を使用してこれらのプロパティにアクセスできます。

[about_intrinsic_members - 組み込みメンバーについて](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.3)も参照してください。

この説明に従い、

```
$dht.GetKeyBlock = { $args[0] }
```

を

```
$dht.psbase.GetKeyBlock = { $args[0] }
```

と改めれば、`HashTable`にキーを追加することなく、プロパティに値を代入できるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 実際に確認してみたところ、ご指摘通りにすることで期待した動きが得られました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

さしあたり(問題含みですが)現象を回避する方法を見つけたので自己回答しておきます。なお、この方法以外のもっと良い方法をご存知でしたら是非ご教授ください。

HashTableのKeysに対するアクセッサをオーバーライドすることで、Keysに対するアクセス結果に干渉できる。

```
    [System.Collections.ICollection]get_Keys(){
       $keys =([HashTable]$this).get_keys()
       return([System.Collections.ICollection]($keys.where{ $_ -ne ***ExclueNeeded*** }))
    }
```

(この方法だと、特定の文字列を含めることのできないHashTableになってしまうため、十分な策とは言えません)